# isInvalid prop isn't highlighting the input box red - react-bootstrap form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using React along with react-bootstrap for creating forms.

I have a form with an email field like this -

[image]

Code -

```
<Form
  noValidate
  autoComplete="off"
  validated={this.state.validated}
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
>
  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="email">
    <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
      type="email"
      aria-describedby="email"
      placeholder="Email"
      value={this.state.email}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      name="email"
      required
    />
    <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
      Please enter your email
    </Form.Control.Feedback>
  </Form.Group>
  <Button type="submit">Register</Button>
</Form>
```

I know that if I want to keep showing the error message even if the user has filled the field I can do this -
`<Form.Control isInvalid={true}>`

But this doesn't remove the green border and the tick mark, and the form still gets submitted. Only the invalid message is visible
[image]

Is there any way or any class name that I can specify so that react-bootstrap doesn't consider the field as validated?

I want to do this as the email validation in react bootstrap forms considers this as a correct email - `my@email`. So, I want to apply custom validation.

Answer (score 1):

When using a Form.Control.Feedback element with type="invalid", you must also use the isInvalid property on the Form.Control, ie isInvalid={true}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `isValid={false}` prop to <Form.Control />. It should do it. For more info see the docs [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/?).

Comment: Do you have both like this `<Form.Control isInvalid={true} isValid={false} ... />` ? if so, the green styling is there? Is it still submitting?

Comment: Yes, it is still submitting and green styling's there